# Fetching email from multiple accounts via both Lieer (gmailieer) and isync with Notmuch

Tags: doom, notmuch

I was wondering if I can use both isync and Lieer (gmailieer) at the same time to pull email from multiple Gmail and multiple non-Gmail accounts (each account  being in a separate subdirectory in my mail directory which is where Notmuch resides)? I know I am asking this before trying but I have sensitive Email setup and I am worried I might mess things up. I really like having access to my Gmail tags, that's why I started using Lieer. I tried to fetching non-Gmail accounts through Lieer and it (maybe obviously) fails, that's why I am looking to use isync for other accounts. Is there anything I should be aware or careful about with regards to: a. Using both Lieer and isync at the same time? b. Having multiple accounts in such a setup (I am also using msmtp to send emails)? c. I am using Doom Emacs, is there anything to be done on that setup?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There was no problem doing that. The only thing to do is to add `mbsync -a` to pre-new hook for Notmuch.